# Incrementing not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble getting numNotes to increment. Everything else seems to work just fine.

```
function getNotes(done) {
  noteSchema.find({}).exec((err, notes) => {
    var numNotes = 0;
    async.each(notes, (n, next) => {
        userSchema.findById(n.userId, (err, user) => {
        if (err || !user) { next(); return; }
        var emailsStr = utils.getEmailsString(user.emails);
            if (!utils.toSkipEmail(emailsStr)) {
                meetingSchema.findById(n.meetingId, function (err, meeting) {
                    if (meeting.name.displayValue.indexOf('test', 'Test') == -1) {
                        numNotes++;
                    }
                });
            }
            next();
        })
    }, (err, result) => {
      console.log(util.format('Total Number of Notes: %d', numNotes));
      done(null);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: add a breakpoint?  Add a console.log().  You need to know if it is actually getting to the line to increment ten numNotes.

Comment: thank you. Yes, I had a console.log() line before the numNotes; incrementation to log the results of the if statement and the results came out as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your `next()` might be getting invoked before `numNotes++` is ever run. This is because Node.JS is [non-blocking](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/10/30/understanding-node-js/) and doesn't run your code sequentially if there are async functions present.

To see the previous in action place a `console.log('test 1')` after `if(!utils.toSkipEmail(emailsStr))`, a `console.log('test 2')` after the `if (meeting.name.displayValue.indexOf('test', 'Test') == -1){...}` block, and also a `console.log('test3')` after the `if(!utils.toSkipEmail(emailsStr)){...}` block.

In order to fix your issue try the following:

```
if (!utils.toSkipEmail(emailsStr)) {

  meetingSchema.findById(n.meetingId, function(err, meeting) {
    if (meeting.name.displayValue.indexOf('test', 'Test') == -1) {
      numNotes++;
    }
    next();
  });
} else {
  next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked after some adjusting. It's really hard to get those next(); lines right!